# Colorbox multiple divs needs extra click

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm having a problem that I thought someone else might have a quick answer for.  I'm attempting to use a Colorbox to display multiple hidden inline divs.  The first div is displayed correctly on load.  When I click on one of the anchors, nothing happens.  If I click again, the correct div shows.  Is there a way not to require the extra click?

Here's my HTML:

```
<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>
<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content2">More inline HTML</a></a></p>
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
<p><strong>Inline content.</strong></p>
</div>
<div id='inline_content2' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
<p><strong>Different inline content.</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, open: true, rel: 'inline', current: "", width:"50%"});
 });
```

Exhibits the behavior described above in Opera, Firefox, Chrome.  Doesn't do anything in IE.  I'm using the most current versions of jQuery, Colorbox.